# Знак "Партсобрание" странно работает

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки, выборы

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/80/caucus

> Посетить выборы на **любом из активных этапов** и иметь достаточно высокую репутацию для участия в голосовании. Знак можно получать многократно.

Но человек почему-то получил бадж и за прошлые выборы, хотя очевидно, что они не были активны на тот момент.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [обсуждению на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335091/260198), это следствие объединения аккаунтов. В момент мёрджа дата объединения станет датой получения знаков с объединённого профиля.